# How to modify TEXMFHOME in texmaker on Mac when running a command?

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, texmf

I have got a complex latex document that we are meant to compile using make. It works fine but I would prefer to use texmaker. However, in the Makefile I can see that I need to modify TEXMFHOME and TEXINPUTS before running pdflatex :

`TEXMFHOME=misc//:$(TEXMFHOME) TEXINPUTS=.//:$(TEXINPUTS) "/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode master.tex`

I tried to configure the command in texmaker to do the same but it seems just to ignore the variables and of course doesn't find all necessary files.

Is there a way to modify TEXMFHOME in texmaker ?

Comment: The `$(TEXMFHOME)` and `$(TEXINPUTS)` bits are wrong. The normal setting of `TEXINPUTS` is already to have the working directory at the start.

Comment: @egreg I would rather say that the TEXINPUTS bit is useless, but for sure the TEXMFHOME is needed. If I omit it, the compilation fails due to missing files (the ones in misc).

Comment: @egreg but note the `//` after the dot, which causes to recursively search in all the subdirectories, which (I think) TeX doesn't do by default

Comment: @Barth You can write a bash script which sets the variables and calls pdflatex, and instruct TeXmaker to run that script instead of pdflatex.

Comment: @JLDiaz If you ask `echo $TEXINPUTS`, the answer will be empty. The variable is set up only during the run of a program. Saying `TEXINPUTS=.//:` will append the value assigned to `TEXINPUTS` by `texmf.cnf`. You're right that usually only `.` is at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer this strictly for the Mac -- although it's in parts unix as well -- but I just stumbled over this questions while googling for the same issue with Texmaker under Ubuntu 12.04.

I have some packages under ~/texmf that are required for successful compilation. On the command-line I've used

```
export TEXMFHOME=~/texmf
```

so how to make Texmaker understand that as well? Of course, it works if you have launched Texmaker from the command-line (then it's got all your exported environment variables) but not if it's been launched from Ubuntu's dash thingy.

Short answer to long babble is that

```
pdflatex ... %.tex TEXMFHOME=~/texmf
```

did it for me. The trick was to postpend not prepend the environment variable.